# xterm-for-react with xterm-addon-fit throws unable to read properties error (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, xtermjs

I am using xterm-for-react for terminal integration and I want to resize that terminal window as my wrapper div tag around the component changes.. For that I am using xterm addon fit but on changing the height of my wrapper div also it isn't working.. Also I know that xterm-for-react has one more div which wrapes the real xterm, I tried to put a resize observer on that as well but it didn't work.. first of all the fitAddon itself throws some error saying it is not able to read properties of null.. reading scrollback. Please help if anyone knows how to resolve this resizing issue.

`xterm-addon-fit.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollback') at t.FitAddon.proposeDimensions (xterm-addon-fit.js:1:916) at t.FitAddon.fit (xterm-addon-fit.js:1:414) at ResizeObserver.<anonymous> (EdrEndpointDetails.js:313:64)`

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Update to the latest versions of `xterm` and addons, currently like so:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "xterm": "^5.3.0",
  "xterm-addon-attach": "^0.9.0",
  "xterm-addon-fit": "^0.8.0"
},
```

---

I ran into this error as well, except with the `cell` property:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cell')
    at t.FitAddon.proposeDimensions
```

I was using the following code when I ran into the issue, I didn't have the mentioned `xterm-for-react` lib:

```js
import { FitAddon } from "xterm-addon-fit";
import { Terminal } from "xterm";

const term = new Terminal({ cols: 40, rows: 30 });
const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
term.loadAddon(fitAddon);
term.open(containerElement);

// This line caused the error
fitAddon.fit();
```

Looking through the code of the imported library, we can see that the funcion `proposeDimensions` is defined [here](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/master/addons/xterm-addon-fit/src/FitAddon.ts#L49). I found the offending code that references `cell` within the function:

```js
const core = (this._terminal as any)._core;
const dims: IRenderDimensions = core._renderService.dimensions;

if (dims.css.cell.width === 0 || dims.css.cell.height === 0) {
  return undefined;
}

...

const geometry = {
  cols: Math.max(MINIMUM_COLS, Math.floor(availableWidth / dims.css.cell.width)),
  rows: Math.max(MINIMUM_ROWS, Math.floor(availableHeight / dims.css.cell.height))
};
```

I found [a similar issue](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/4136) that discussed updating the library versions to resolve errors, so I gave that a go and it worked! The legacy project I inherited didn't require any code changes to do so, the upgrade was completely painless.

Comment: still happens 
{
    "faker": "^6.6.6",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "xterm": "^5.3.0",
    "xterm-addon-fit": "^0.8.0",
    "xterm-for-react": "^1.0.4"
  },